# Large Multicolumn table in latex

Tags: tables, longtable, multicolumn

I am trying to reproduce the following table in latex. However I am not able to get the desired output. Can someone help me to construct this table in latex?

[image]

So far I have tried the following but it fails to produce the desired result.
Any help will be largely appreciated!

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,blue,allowframebreaks 12pt,psfig]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

  \hline

 Semester & Sem 1 & Sem 2 & Sem 3 & Sem 4 & Sem 5 & Sem 6 & Sem 7 & Sem 8 \\ 
 \hline

  Major & 4 Credits (100 level) & 4 Credits (100 level) & 4 Credits (200 & above) &  16 Credits  (200 level) & 14 Credits (300 level) & 16 Credits (300 level) & 16 Credits (400 level) & 16 Credits (400 level) & 4 Credit (400level) & \\ 
  
\hline

Minor & 4.94e-04 & 5.50e-02 & 3.52e-06 &  17 & 0.38 & 0.61 & 0.13 &\\ 
   \
\hline
   
*Courses from other disciplines (Multidisplinary) & 1.16e-06 & 6.65e-02 & 5.54e-08 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.62 & 0.28 &\\ 
   
\hline
 
Ability Enhancement Courses (AEC), MIL, English Language, Communication Skills & 1.27e-05 & 8.61e-02 & 5.20e-07 &  10 & 0.53 & 0.66 & 0.27 &\\ 
 
\hline

Skill Enhancement Courses (SEC)/Internship/Dissertation & 2.49e-05 & 1.31e+00 & 4.27e-05 &  13 & 0.61 & 0.74 & 0.26 & \\ 
 
\hline
 Value Added Courses (VAC), EVS, JU, Digital and Technological Solutions, Health and Wellness,Yoga Education, Sports and Fitness & 8.73e-33 & 1.41e+00 & 3.49e-08 &  44 & 0.55 & 0.48 & 0.12 &\\ 
 
\hline

Total Credits (120 credits)-3 Yr UG Degree (160 credits)-4 Yr UG Degree & 2.92e-06 & 1.92e+00 & 1.03e-07 &  10 & 0.66 & 0.73 & 0.27 &\\
   
\hline

\end{tabular}}

\caption{CBCS Structure of the Four Year Undergraduate Programme (FYUGP)} 

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. Can you please Edit your qeustion and provide the preamble, too?

Comment: I have added my preamble as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This web page can help you to create any type of table at the following address: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Answer (score 1):

- It is not entirely clear, how your table should look. MWE is broken, showed image is unclear.
- table is huge, so it present in frame is quite fragile ...
- possible solution (based on guessing) can be:

  - use `tiny` font size
  - enable multiline text in the first column (by use `tabularx` package)
  - redesign column headers (introduce one more text lines
  - locally increase text width by use of the `changepage` package

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
%
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{changepage}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{table}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2em}{-2em}
\tiny%\fontsize{6pt}{7pt}\selectfont
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright}X| *{8}{c|}}
  \hline
 Semester    & Sem 1    & Sem 2     & Sem 3     & Sem 4     & Sem 5     & Sem 6     & Sem 7     & Sem 8         \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{=}{Major}       
            & 4 Credits & 4 Credits & 4 Credits & 16 Credits&14 Credits &16 Credits &16 Credits & 16 Credits    \\
            & (100 level)
                        & (100 level)
                                    & (200 above)
                                                & (200 level)
                                                            & (300 level)
                                                                        & (300 level)
                                                                                    & (400 level)
                                                                                                & (400 level)   \\
%                                                                            & 4 Credit (400level) & \\
    \hline
Minor       & 4.94e-04  & 5.50e-02  & 3.52e-06  & 17        & 0.38      & 0.61      & 0.13      &               \\
    \hline
*Courses from other disciplines (Multidisplinary) 
            & 1.16e-06  & 6.65e-02  & 5.54e-08  & 10        & 0.52      & 0.62      & 0.28      &               \\
    \hline
Ability Enhancement Courses (AEC), MIL, English Language, Communication Skills 
            & 1.27e-05  & 8.61e-02  & 5.20e-07  & 10        & 0.53      & 0.66      & 0.27      &               \\
    \hline
Skill Enhancement Courses (SEC) /Internship/Dissertation 
            & 2.49e-05  & 1.31e+00  & 4.27e-05  & 13        & 0.61      & 0.74      & 0.26      &               \\
    \hline
Value Added Courses (VAC), EVS, JU, Digital and Technological Solutions, Health and Wellness,Yoga Education, Sports and Fitness     & 8.73e-33  & 1.41e+00  & 3.49e-08  & 44        & 0.55      & 0.48      & 0.12      &               \\
    \hline
Total Credits (120 credits)-3 Yr UG Degree (160 credits)-4 Yr UG Degree 
            & 2.92e-06  & 1.92e+00  & 1.03e-07  & 10        & 0.66      & 0.73      & 0.27      &               \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{CBCS Structure of the Four Year Undergraduate Programme (FYUGP)}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]